# What would be causing a "recursion requested but not available" error using dbndns?

Tags: domain-name-system, dig, tinydns

The tinydns and dnscache services are running and I have 127.0.0.1 in my resolv.conf:

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.1
domain localdomain
search localdomain

root@ubuntu:~# sv status /etc/service/*
run: /etc/service/dnscache: (pid 927) 22s; run: log: (pid 663) 517s
run: /etc/service/tinydns: (pid 898) 418s; run: log: (pid 660) 517s

root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/service/dnscache/env/IP
127.0.0.1

root@ubuntu:~# dig @192.168.17.139 joe.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.1-P2 <<>> @192.168.17.139 joe.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35794
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;joe.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
joe.com.        300 IN  A   1.1.1.1

<snip>
```

Why would I get "WARNING: recursion requested but not available" when running dig. I believe it should be able to recurse using dnscache.

Answer (score 4):

Which ports and IP addresses are the two servers bound to?

It looks like you might have `tinydns` (authoritative) on the `192.168.17.139` address, and dnscache (recursive) only on the loopback interface.

If so, you need to use `dig @127.0.0.1` to talk to the recursive cache, or even just omit the IP address from the `dig` command line, at which point it'll default to using whatever's in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Correct, tinydns: 192.168.17.139, dnscache: 127.0.0.1. What you suggest works properly. I have another tinydns installation (not dbndns) that does not give me this warning. Seeing how dbndns/tinydns aren't recursive DNS servers shouldn't they always return "WARNING: recursion requested but not available"?

Comment: Yup, a DNS server that's _only_ authoritative must send back an answer with the `RA` bit clear.  Similarly the `RD` bit must be copied from the request to the response.  If the server fails to copy the RD bit you won't see that warning.